# client_Browser field is always empty in App Insights

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, appinsights

For all requests in App Insights the property `client_Browser` is empty for some reason. 
How can I make App insights populate `client_Browser` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature(client_os, client_browser are populated in app insights) has been deprecated for a long time, see the [issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/902).

As of now, `client_Browser` is only populated in the `pageViews telemetry`, but not in `request telemetry`.

Here is the screenshot of `pageViews telemetry`:

[image]

If you just want to query the requests based on which browser, you can simply join `pageViews table` and `requests table` via `session_Id` in the Application Insights logs.

Also, [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/34591504-populate-client-browser-and-client-os-for-requests) is the request feature about this, please upvote it.

Comment: I don't have any `pageViews` as I don't track client-side, hoped that server side would work. Thanks for letting know.

Comment: The third thing I had to wonder about - why it stopped working?...