# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy + Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-application-insights

I'm using a TechnicalProfile for logging custom events to Application Insights in Azure AD B2C, but I would like to add the client OS or client type. Now all clients are set as PC.

Is this possible?

The trace logging from AD B2C to Application Insights also logs all events as client type PC.

Answer (score 0):

Client_os, Client_browser are not populated in application insights.This has been deprecated for a long time, see the issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/902).

A similar feature has been requested in Azure UserVoice.​
Please vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/34591504-populate-client-browser-and-client-os-for-requests) to raise your concern.​

Comment: Check a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60546367/client-browser-field-is-always-empty-in-app-insights/60558779#60558779)